# how to get a record via the ManyToMany link

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

1

I want to get the email of the restaurant through the order model. How can I do this?

My models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    cart_meal = models.ManyToManyField(CartMeal, null=True, blank=True)

class CartMeal(models.Model):
    meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, verbose_name='Meal', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meal(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
```

I need to get to restaurant.email via order. I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work: `order.cart_meal.model.meal.restaurant.email`

I get the order this way
views.py

```
@action(methods=['PUT'], detail=False, url_path='current_customer_cart/add_to_order')
    def add_cart_to_order(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cart = Cart.objects.get(owner=self.request.user.customer)
        cart_meals = CartMeal.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        data = self.request.data

        for restaurant, cart_meals in itertools.groupby(CartMeal.objects.filter(cart=cart).order_by('meal__restaurant'),
                                                        lambda s: s.meal.restaurant):
            order = Order.objects.create(
                customer=self.request.user.customer,
                first_name=data['first_name'],
                last_name=data['last_name'],
                phone=data['phone'],
                address=data.get('address', self.request.user.customer.home_address),
            )
            order.cart_meal.set([cart_meal for cart_meal in cart_meals])
            
            cooking_meal_notification(**restaurant_email=???**)
```

In calling the last method `cooking_meal_notification`, I need to get the email of the restaurant

sender.py

```
def cooking_meal_notification(restaurant_email, meal):
    send_mail(
        'An order has been received',
        meal,
        'kudlasevich.nikita@gmail.com',
        [restaurant_email],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

Comment: Your `Order` can have multiple meals from multiple restaurants, or at least that is how it has been modelled). Does your application actively prevents this?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My English is bad. But I would like to say that there can be many meals from different restaurants in the order, this is true. If I understood your question correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple `Restaurant`s since an `Order` can contain multiple meals that are produced by different `Restaurant`s.

You can retrieve a `QuerySet` of the related `Restaurant`s with:

```
Restaurant.objects.filter(
    meal__cartmeal__order=order
).distinct()
```

We can thus retrieve the email addresses of these `Restaurant`s with:

```
Restaurant.objects.filter(
    meal__cartmeal__order=order
).values_list('email', flat=True).distinct()
```

This thus produces an iterable of email addresses of the `Restaurant`s related to that order.

You can for example use this to call call a function like `cooking_meal_notification`:

```
qs = Restaurant.objects.filter(
    meal__cartmeal__order=order
).values_list('email', flat=True).distinct()

for email in qs:
    cooking_meal_notification(email)
```

You can also work with the `Meal`s that are "members" of the `Order`:

```
qs = Meal.objects.filter(
    cartmeal__order=order
).select_related('restaurant')

for meal in qs:
    cooking_meal_notification(meal.restaurant.email, meal)
```

Comment: I need to get mail in this function:

cooking_meal_notification(restaurant_email=???)

Comment: and I create an order this way: for restaurant, cart_meals in itertools.groupby(CartMeal.objects.filter(cart=cart).order_by('meal__restaurant'), lambda s: s.meal.restaurant):
 order = Order.objects.create(...)
order.cart_meal.set([cart_meal for cart_meal in cart_meals])

Comment: @nikitaex: the second code fragment is a collection of email addresses. You thus can use a loop (`for email in last_queryset: cooking_meal_notification(restaurant_email=email)`

Comment: @nikitaex: see update.

Comment: Can you please watch the update of the post?

Comment: @nikitaex: see update.

Comment: Oh, my God, you're a wizard! Thank you very much, I wouldn't know what to do without you!